# Image acting weird inside a scroll view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Why when I have a an image inside a scroll view is it getting all zoomed the image is only 200pixels across in height and width

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Both">
    <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="logo.png" HeightRequest="200" 
            WidthRequest="200"></Image>
            <dxg:DataGridView x:Name="dgSessions" 
             BackgroundColor="Black" 
                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        Tap="dgSessions_Tap"                              
                        HeightRequest="1000" >
                <dxg:DataGridView.CellStyle>
                    <dxg:CellStyle  
                    BackgroundColor="#333333" 
                    BorderColor="#515151"
    FontSize="14" FontColor="White" 
    SelectionColor="#f78a09" SelectionFontColor="Black"/>
                </dxg:DataGridView.CellStyle>
                <dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderStyle >
                    <dxg:ColumnHeaderStyle  
            BackgroundColor="#333333" BorderColor="#515151" 
            FontSize="16" FontColor="#929292" 
            Padding="10,10,10,10" FontAttributes="Bold" 
            HorizontalLineThickness="2"/>
                </dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <dxg:DataGridView.Columns >
                    <dxg:TextColumn  FieldName="Name" 
                  Caption="Name" Width="300" />
                    <dxg:DateColumn  FieldName="StartDate" 
                    Caption="Start Date" Width="150" />
                    <dxg:DateColumn  FieldName="EndDate" 
                    Caption="End Date" Width="180" />
                    <dxg:TemplateColumn FieldName="Id" 
                    Caption="Actions"
                    IsReadOnly="true" AllowSort="False" 
                       Width="200">
        <dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <syncfusion:SfButton  Text="Add Student" 
       Clicked="btnAddStudentToSession_Clicked"  
      x:Name="btnAddStudentToSession" ></syncfusion:SfButton>
        <syncfusion:SfButton  Text="Add Team" 
        Clicked="btnAddTeamToSession_Clicked"  
       x:Name="btnAddTeamToSession" ></syncfusion:SfButton>

                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </dxg:TemplateColumn.DisplayTemplate>
                    </dxg:TemplateColumn>
                </dxg:DataGridView.Columns>
            </dxg:DataGridView>
        </StackLayout>
```

You will see here its shows perfect however I wont have any scroll it stays fixed weird

[image]
But if I have the

But if i remove the height restrictions on my image the scroll view works as expected. But the image is super zoomed in and very big ?

[image]

Comment: Your scroll view scrolls in both directions, and you've used a StackLayout as your scrolling view. This means that the StackLayout is expanding unimpeded both vertically and horizontally to allow its content to use its desired space. I'm not quite sure what the problem is and what your desired outcome is.

Comment: The logo showed be the correct height and size as shown in the first pick but still allow scrolling

Comment: Are you sure that there is enough content that scrolling is possible? It seems to me that you cannot scroll because there's not any content overflowing the ScrollView's viewport that you could scroll to.

Comment: their is content its their an extra column with 2 buttons

Comment: Never mind I solved it by changing my buttons to use a grid within the devexpress template columns seems to have fixed it and now the content is fine on the device thanks